# What's the Objective-C convention for logging out/purging data?

Tags: ios, oop, session, core-data, conventions

We have a way to purge data from views, a way to purge data from Core Data, a login screen view controller to present, and a way to delete our session object.

Now undoubtedly we'll need these together to logout and show the login screen. Should there be a function in the appdelegate, or another class specifically for this functionality, or handled individually by wherever we need to logout from?

What's the Objective-C convention for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a user object, or a user controller to manage this functionality, right? So that should do it.

The app delegate is for app level event handling, not user management.

Objective-C is a language so it has no convention for user management.

Duplicating the logout code "wherever needed" is bad design. This is really a pure OOP question and you need to define classes and allocate responsibility and ownership accordingly.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. Why is the User model responsible for cleaning the data from each of the views? Why should it delete the data of models it may not be connected to?


Since User is far too general I'd say there should be a Session class to handle these things. But I'm not sure if it should be responsible for deleting the model and view data too.

Comment: Presumably it owns the session and core data content and purges those. That is observed by any views which are currently on display and related. Login is a separate action to logout purge so I don't see how login presentation is connected.

Comment: Well usually after you've just logged out you'd want to present the login screen again.

Comment: If that's the case then you're basically throwing away the entire user interface so some root view controller would be observing the logout event and wiping the UI.